# Is there a way to find out if my package or table is accessed via a DB Link

Tags: oracle

Is there a way to find out if my package or table is accessed via a DB Link?

I have a schema which is accessed via db link and direct connection. I can get the dependencies fine, but I really would like to see if there is a way to tell if the object used is via a db link vs direct connection.

```
select * from dba_dependencies d , dba_synonyms s 
where d.owner in ('MY_SCHEMA') 
and d.referenced_owner = 'PUBLIC'
and d.referenced_type='SYNONYM'
and d.referenced_name = s.synonym_name
and s.owner='PUBLIC'
and s.table_owner not in ('MY_SCHEMA')
```

Is there a way other than checking the remote databases. I would prefer to do this from the source database.

Comment: Maybe describing [the DBA_SYNONYMS view](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2091.htm#REFRN20273) might give you a clue???

Comment: Change the db link to point to a dedicated schema. In that schema, create private synonyms for the objects the remote db needs, and apply the necessary grants so it can use them. That way, you know for sure that the remote db can't use objects it isn't supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Using user_db_links.  db links accessibility is based on schema not by indivial objects like package,  procedure,  table etc